# Given an Iterated System of Functions, how to find an estimate of the fractal dimension of the image?

Tags: fractals, iterated-function-system

Given an Iterated System of Functions, say $f_1,...,f_n$, with associated transition probabilities $\sigma_{ij}$ for each $f_{i}$ to each $f_{j}$, how do we go about finding an estimate to the fractal dimension?

**Motivation:** For other methods of generating fractals, like recursive maps where we can define the n-th value $X_n$ in terms of the value $X_{n-1}$, we have many different methods to estimate the fractal dimension.For example, using the box counting technique on different values of N, and taking that limit as it approaches infinity. With techniques like these, we can also sometimes yield exact values of the fractal dimension.

**My attempt:** I've tried modelling the transitions of the IFS as a Markov Chain and finding the orbit of each function. If the orbit is finite, I'm thinking there might be a way to use its encoding to generate a number which could be used in the estimate of the dimension of the resulting fractal.

I am not sure if this is the right direction to take and if it is, how to proceed from there.

Comment: The scale factor of each function is most relevant - I think the transition probabilities don't affect the dimension, only whether they are zero or non-zero.  (The probabilitiies might affect multifractal spectrum? Not sure..)  In that case I think you have a graph-directed iterated function system: see http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1988-309-02/S0002-9947-1988-0961615-4/S0002-9947-1988-0961615-4.pdf and https://people.math.osu.edu/edgar.2/preprints/golds/edgar992.pdf

Comment: @Claude Thanks for resource, it looks promising, I was thinking that transition probabilities might affect the dimension, since if we had two functions, one which is much more likely than the other with dimension log(4)/log(3) and the other less likely one with dimension log(2)/log(3), we might get something more weighted towards log(4)/log(3).

Comment: However looking in Munkres' Topology second edition, in the dimension theory chapter it seems that corollary 50.3, tells that if X = Y1 U...U Yn where Yi is a closed subspace of X and is finite dimensional. Then dim(X) = max(dim(Yi)) where dimesion dim is the topological dimesion (which I'm not sure if that is equivalent to Hausdorff dimension). I guess I'll try drawing up a proof that applies to an IFS.